# how to get the list of default users in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

is there an sql query which extract the default users ?
i tried :

> describe DBA_USERS

but i didn't find any column which indicate that the user is a default user or not !

Comment: I don't know how to query that list, but you can find it [on orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/List_of_default_database_users).

Comment: i need it in a query to use them in another query

Comment: I can't find it, and actually it would surprise me if a flag like that actually exists in the user table. After all, it's just a bunch of users that is created right away, but apart from that they are not really special. 

However, `DBA_USERS` has one column, `CREATED`, which contains the date on which the user was created, so maybe you can check that date. The oldest users will be the users that were automatically created when you created the database.